# Why can a SQL Server table not have more than one IDENTITY column?

Tags: sql-server, identity, database-internals

Why can a SQL Server table not have more than one identity column?

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT IDENTITY, id2 INT IDENTITY)
```

> Msg 2744, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
>   Multiple identity columns specified for table 't'.
>   Only one identity column per table is allowed.

I understand we can resolve it using a computed column.

As per the product documentation, a table can not have more than one identity column. But, why? What is the real reason behind it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there's any real "internals" reason. The metadata is stored at column level not table level. It would need a rethink though of scalar functions such as `scope_identity()` and pseudo column syntax such as `$identity` as there would now be ambiguities.

Philosophically if the purpose of `identity` is to produce something that uniquely identifies an entity why would you need two different arbitrary calculated values acting in that role?

And where is the benefit anyway? This is a cross site dupe so [I'll repeat my example from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3807400/73226).

> An Identity Column in SQL Server has a seed and an auto increment. We
>   could always calculate what the 2nd hypothetical id value should be if
>   we knew the value of the first id column anyway.
>
> e.g. If this was legal syntax
>
> ```
> create table #foo
> (
> bar int identity(1,10),
> baz int identity(1000,1)
> )
> ```
>
> We wouldn't need to store baz as it could be calculated from bar as
>   follows.
>
> ```
> baz = 1000 + (bar-1)/10
> ```

Since SQL Server 2012 you can knock yourself out and add as many columns using sequence defaults as you want to a table though. For example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Sequence1 
    AS integer 
    START WITH 1 
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    MAXVALUE 1000 
    CYCLE 
    CACHE 50;

CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Sequence2 
    AS decimal(5,0) 
    START WITH 5
    INCREMENT BY 10
    MAXVALUE 250 
    CYCLE 
    CACHE 50;

CREATE TABLE dbo.T
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequence1, 
    id2 decimal(5,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sequence2, 
);

INSERT dbo.T DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT dbo.T DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT dbo.T DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT * FROM dbo.T;

DROP TABLE dbo.T;

DROP SEQUENCE 
    dbo.Sequence1, 
    dbo.Sequence2;
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **computed** column instead, starting at some value plus the id value:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TwoIdentity (id INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL, SecondID AS 100+id, TEXT VARCHAR(50) NULL)
```

[image]